# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have the following scenario:

- I have a list of list of numbers, for example:

```py
day_list = [
  [317, 331, 344],
  [305, 326, 340],
  [317],
  [290, 323],
  [311, 325, 345],
  [289, 303, 323],
  [274, 281, 294, 325]
  ...
]
```

- I want to subtract the previous element from the next element of each inner list, so that appending the results in a "result" list. Example:

**First list:** [317, 331, 344]

331 - 317 = 14
344 - 331 = 13

**Result list:** [14, 13]

My code is:

```py
result = []
sub_result = []
for index, i in enumerate(day_list):
  if len(i) > 1:
    result = []
    for j in range(len(i)-1):
        subtract = np.subtract(np.array(day_list[index][j+1]), np.array(day_list[index][j]))
        result.append(subtract)
    sub_result.append(result)
  else:
    sub_result.append(0)
```

I'm getting the follow error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)

I see it has to do with the code part in which I change the array position `(j+1)`. And I have no idea how to fix the code and have the proper result.

I've already read a bunch of similar questions, but I could not find a solution.

Could you please help?

Tks

===================================

Adding more details:

I'm creating a list from the following data frame:

```
        key day_list
    0   1078|11498  [317, 331, 344]
    1   1078|11749  [305, 326, 340]
    2   1078|11778  [317]
    3   1078|13974  [290, 323]
    4   1078|15866  [311, 325, 345]
    ... ... ...
    25337   96|426860   [302, 326]
    25338   96|443060   [310]
    25339   96|445134   [301, 303, 310]
    25340   96|445237   [301, 309, 310, 324]
    25341   96|447416   [301, 310]
    25342 rows × 2 columns

    def load_data(data):
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        day_list = []
        for i in range(len(df)):
            day_list.append(df.day_list.loc[i])
        return day_list

    day_list = load_data(df_dayofyear)
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. _I want to subtract the previous element from the next element of each inner list_ Just use [`numpy.diff()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). Speaking of NumPy, why mix Python lists and numpy ndarrays like this? I can see only downsides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it was indentation error in the code which i corrected, I tried this code now and not getting any error:

```
day_list = [[317, 331, 344],
[305, 326, 340],
[317],
[290, 323],
[311, 325, 345],
[289, 303, 323]]
```

```
result = []
sub_result = []
for index, i in enumerate(day_list):
    if len(i) > 1:
        result = []
        for j in range(len(i)-1):
            subtract = np.subtract(np.array(day_list[index][j+1]), np.array(day_list[index][j]))
            result.append(subtract)
        sub_result.append(result)
    else:
        sub_result.append(0)
```

Output:

```
[[14, 13], [21, 14], 0, [33], [14, 20], [14, 20]]
```

Comment: I think the problem is with my list. I created a list manually with the values illustrated here, and the same code worked. I'm generating my list form a dataframe column and it might be causing some issue.

Comment: If you are generating list from your dataframe column, try this - `df[column_name].values.tolist()`

Comment: I found the problem. For some reason, my list was being generated with garbage in the last sublist. I reprocessed everything and  it's working fine now. Many thanks for your help!